# Random "GROUP" of radiobutton?

Tags: android, radio-button

How can i Random "GROUP" of radiobutton?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        objects.add(0);
        objects.add(1);
        objects.add(2);
        objects.add(3);
        objects.add(4);

        Collections.shuffle(objects);

        List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button0));
        buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)); 
        buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2));
        buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button3));
        buttons.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button4));

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        buttons.get(i).setText(objects.get(i).toString());
        }

    }
```

The code about is not a "GROUP" of radio button, how it became a RadioGroup? and display in random order. Anyones help?

Comment: why did you delete the other question? you could just have edited it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a example of creating radio button with radio group....

```
 private void createRadioButton() {

 List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        objects.add(0);
        objects.add(1);
        objects.add(2);
        objects.add(3);
        objects.add(4);

        Collections.shuffle(objects);

            final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[5];
            RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this); //create the RadioGroup
            rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
                rg.addView(rb[i]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
                rb[i].setText(objects.get(i)+"");
            }
            ll.addView(rg);//you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout
            ll.addView(submit); 
            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
                        rg.removeView(rb[i]);//now the RadioButtons are in the RadioGroup
                    }  
                    ll.removeView(submit);

                }
            });   
        }
```

Comment: It is randomly display?

Comment: what you mean by randomly display?

Comment: you can set data to them randomly..?

Comment: how? i'am an newbie in Androi, sorry :(

Comment: you are doing it in your code i guess here...Collections.shuffle(objects);buttons.get(i).setText(objects.get(i).toString());

Comment: Thanks, i'll try. :( but if not succeded can you do it for me? :(

Comment: please do not forget to mark my answer as correct and please upvote it .if i helped you..:)

Comment: there is a correct mark on the answer's left side where there is 1 written . mark it...thanx

Comment: i see :) i always do that :)

Comment: but you didnt for this...is this answer not help full?